# Developing a step counter in Android

Tags: android, gps, android-sensors

I'm working with Android.

I would like to develope a kind of radar in which a group of monster are following you and you can see them in the radar. The problem is I want to do when the player moves (the device) then it reflects in the radar (so you can run away of the monsters...).

I thought using the gps sensor to check the actual position, but I think it's a bad solution because the players will have to active it when they want to play...

So, is there another alternative to this? I saw step counters that checks the movement of the device to count the steps. How they do that?

Thanks.

EDIT: I'm thinking that you have to know where is going the player too. Maybe using the compass?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- http://code.google.com/p/pedometer/
- https://github.com/bagilevi/android-pedometer
- etc.

Sometimes searching is your friend.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I suppose I can't I do what I want without gps sensor... because if you move the mobile, it counts like a step...

Comment: @Frion3L I think if you want to have virtual monsters chasing you on a map your best bet is to use the GPS and just make users turn it on--you could use coarse location, but meh. I'm sure that's how the race-against-yourself apps do it.